# How to test sunspot search results or hits

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot, kaminari

I am getting an error while testing an index page which uses sunspot search.

```
*** NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

The code which i wrote is

```
@object.hits
```

This error also occurs with

```
@object.results
```

I have tried @object.present? , @object.blank? , @object.nil?

I have used kaminari to paginate my results

```
= paginate(@object.hits)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding Model.reindex before my test case.

```
 setup do
   Model.reindex
 end
```